# Inline script routine for Open Sesame experiment

Tags: python, beginner, multithreading

I am new to Python as well as threading and had to build an inline script routine for the use within a Open Sesame Experiment. The Routine should open a program, play tones and catch reaction times. It runs OK so far, but I would be glad for pointing out mistakes and any best practice that I did not follow as I want to refreshen my programming skills.

```
#import os.path
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32process
import win32ui
import win32api
import subprocess
import threading
from openexp.synth import synth
import random
import pythoncom, pyHook, ctypes

""" GAME """
#length of game (s)
playlength = 50

""" SOUND """
# number of tones (best with respective to length and time interval!)
nTones = 5
#length of tone (ms)
soundlength = 60
#frequency of tone (hz)
frequency = 1000
#attack time (ms)
attacktime = 0
#decay time (ms)
decaytime = 0
#random time interval for playing (s)
shortest = 10
longest = 15

""" MISC """
#global response Time Params
responseTime=99
toneStart = 19999
tonePlayed = False
responded = False
strokeResponse = 99
firstTone = True

toneStartLog = []
strokeResponseLog = []
responseTimeLog = []

#global KEY_HANDLER (internal use)
STOP_KEY_HANDLER = False
STOP_TETRIS = False

#gameplay variables
gameStarted = 99
gameEnded = 99
keyStrokes = 0

#IntervallTimes for tones (pseudo random)
# !!! Make sure you change the logging as well (bottom mainthread function) when using more intervalls
totalexptime = 45
intervallTimes = [10.0,10.0]
#intervallTimes = [15.689,17.313,15.822,16.227,18.717,17.027,14.401,16.634,15.797,15.357,10.336,11.454,17.464,14.889,16.649,11.421,13.407,10.964,15.613,12.457]
#total seconds: 297.638

#---------------------------------------------------------
#User Settings:
SaveDirectory=r'C:\...'
#---------------------------------------------------------


class KeyHandler(threading.Thread):
    # create a hook manager
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()
    n = 0

    def __init__(self): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 

    def OnKeyboardCharEvent(self,event):
        global STOP_KEY_HANDLER
        global strokeResponse
        global tonePlayed
        global toneStart
        global keyStrokes

        global tonePlayedLog
        global toneStartLog
        global strokeResponseLog
        global responseTimeLog
        global responded

        if STOP_KEY_HANDLER:
            self.killKey()

        if event.Key=='E':
            strokeResponse = time.clock()
            if (tonePlayed):
                print "added to log tic", time.clock()

                #asap
                responseTime = strokeResponse-toneStart
                tonePlayed = False

                #log for later experiment logging
                toneStartLog.append(toneStart)
                strokeResponseLog.append(strokeResponse)
                responseTimeLog.append(responseTime)

                responded = True

        if event.Key=='Return':

            #send return to put nothing in highscore
            for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
                win32gui.PostMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)

            #take score screenshot
            screenshot() # afaik blocks entire main thread so reaction times do not get affected

            time.sleep(0.2)

            #send F2 to start new game 
            for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
                win32gui.PostMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F2, 0) 

        keyStrokes = keyStrokes + 1

        return True


    def killKey(self):
        KeyHandler.hm.UnhookKeyboard() 
        ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0) 


    def run(self):
        # watch for all keyboard events
        KeyHandler.hm.KeyDown = self.OnKeyboardCharEvent
        # set the hook
        KeyHandler.hm.HookKeyboard()
        # activate message pipeline
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()


class ToneTimer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self) 

    def playSound(self):    #play sound and log reaction time

        global soundlength
        global frequency
        global attacktime
        global decaytime
        global toneStart
        global tonePlayed
        global responded
        global firstTone

        # create synthesizer object - lower freq = lower tone ;), length in ms
        mySynth = synth(exp, osc="sine",freq=frequency,length=soundlength,attack=attacktime,decay=decaytime)
        mySynth.stop_after(soundlength)

        if responded == False and firstTone == False:
                toneStartLog.append(-99)
                strokeResponseLog.append(-99)
                responseTimeLog.append(-99)

        mySynth.play()
        toneStart = time.clock()
        tonePlayed = True
        firstTone = False

    def run(self):
        global STOP_KEY_HANDLER
        global STOP_TETRIS
        global nTones
        global playlength
        global shortest
        global longest
        global gameEnded
        global intervallTimes
        global totalexptime

        # Start = Experiment time start
        expStart = time.clock()
        # Intervall counter
        it=0
        # Release time
        ptillfivemin=0

        # Play all sounds in Intervall times
        for x in intervallTimes:

            ptillfivemin=ptillfivemin+intervallTimes[it]
            time.sleep(intervallTimes[it])
            self.playSound()
            it = it+1

        time.sleep(totalexptime-ptillfivemin)
        expEnd = time.clock()

        STOP_KEY_HANDLER = True

        # backup send key to kill handler - not pretty but works if routine does not stop
        for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
            win32gui.PostMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F5, 0)

        # sleep to make sure processing is done
        time.sleep(0.1)

        # log stuff
        logToExperiment()

        # sleep to make sure processing is done
        time.sleep(0.5)

        # kill Tetris window
        gameEnded = time.clock()

        # take a screenshot to know score
        screenshot()

        # sleep to make sure processing is done
        time.sleep(0.1)

        # kill tetris finish routine
        finished()


""" ---- Main thread functions ---- """

# get hands on a Windows GUI Window (Tetris) by checking windows handlers
def get_hwnds_for_pid (pid):
  def callback (hwnd, hwnds):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible (hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled (hwnd):
      _, found_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId (hwnd)
      if found_pid == pid:
        hwnds.append (hwnd)
    return True

  hwnds = []
  win32gui.EnumWindows (callback, hwnds)
  return hwnds


# make a screenshot and save to path "SaveDirectory"
def screenshot():
    global SaveDirectory
    img=ImageGrab.grab()
    saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,"VP"+str(exp.get('subject_nr'))+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")+'.jpg')
    print saveas
    img.save(saveas)

# finish with closing the Tetris window
def finished():
    for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
        win32gui.SendMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)


# log to experiment
def logToExperiment():

    global toneStartLog
    global strokeResponseLog
    global responseTimeLog
    global keyStrokes

    exp.set('TStart_RTT01',toneStartLog[0])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT02',toneStartLog[1])
    """exp.set('TStart_RTT03',toneStartLog[2])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT04',toneStartLog[3])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT05',toneStartLog[4])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT06',toneStartLog[5])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT07',toneStartLog[6])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT08',toneStartLog[7])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT09',toneStartLog[8])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT10',toneStartLog[9])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT11',toneStartLog[10])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT12',toneStartLog[11])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT13',toneStartLog[12])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT14',toneStartLog[13])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT15',toneStartLog[14])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT16',toneStartLog[15])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT17',toneStartLog[16])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT18',toneStartLog[17])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT19',toneStartLog[18])
    exp.set('TStart_RTT20',toneStartLog[19])"""

    exp.set('SResponse_RTT01',strokeResponseLog[0])
    exp.set('SResponse_RTT02',strokeResponseLog[1])
    """18 more variables that were commented were deleted for so"""

    exp.set('ResponseTime_RTT01',responseTimeLog[0])
    exp.set('ResponseTime_RTT02',responseTimeLog[1])
    """18 more variables that were commented were deleted for so"""

    exp.set('keyStrokes_RTT',keyStrokes)
    exp.set('playtime_Tetris', gameEnded-gameStarted)
    exp.set('APM_RTT', ((keyStrokes/(gameEnded-gameStarted))*60))
    print 'keyStrokes', keyStrokes



""" ---- Main Routine ---- """
# open Tetris
Tetris = subprocess.Popen (["C:...\Tetris.exe"])

# sleep to give the window time to appear
time.sleep (2.0)

# start game by sending "F2" key
for hwnd in get_hwnds_for_pid (Tetris.pid):
  win32gui.PostMessage (hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F2, 0)

gameStarted = time.clock()

# create and setup threads - routine finishes when STOP_KEY_HANDLER is True after timout and key gets invoked
keyH = KeyHandler()
ToneT = ToneTimer()

keyH.setDaemon(True)
ToneT.setDaemon(True)

keyH.start()
ToneT.start()
```

Comment: it = it+1 is the same as it+=1 and the latter is considered best practice.  Other than that, I really can't complain about it too much.

Comment: thank you for the remark, i read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python) and was a bit scared ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class `Sound` like this:

```
class Sound:
   nTones = 5
   soundLength = 60
   frequency = 1000
   attackTime = 0
   decayTime = 0
   shortest = 10
   longest = 15
```

Note that I have changed the name `soundlength` to `soundLength`. Please follow a naming standard. Also the variable names *shortest* and *longest* do not signify their purpose. Instead of writing long comments, I would suggest you to give meaningful names to the variable.

Also create a class `Misc` (or `Game`) as follows:

```
class Game:
   responseTime=99
   toneStart = 19999
   tonePlayed = False
   responded = False
   strokeResponse = 99
   ...
```

Now instead of defining global variables inside the classes you can directly access the class variables from `Game` and `Sound` classes.

In class `KeyHandler` modify the if conditions like following:

```
self.e = 'E'
self.return = 'Return'
....
....
if event.Key == self.e:
...
...
if event.Key == self.return:
```

Avoid using parenthesis in if conditions. Replace

```
if (tonePlayed):
```

with

```
if tonePlayed:
```

Write the main routine inside a `main()` function and call this function like the following

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time! I assume that you want me to define these classes (game, sound) and create an instance of it, and of which i can then access the class variables in the functions e.g. playsound() ?

Comment: i could not use self.return but had to use self.ret, also the construction of the main function will not work with opensesame

Comment: Yes, even i forgot. You cannot use self.return because return is a keyword in python. But I am not sure why main function is causing problem.

Comment: could be due to the environment